# Hiding UILabel based on TableView Selection

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am having a hard time figuring out this problem. 
******Note: I am using a split view controller*****
I am attempting to hide UILabels based on the value of a tableView cell that is selected.

Example:

Below is the tableView I have and when I selected a cell data populates in the detailView.  [image]

DetailView

[image]

Essentially I have too much data that needs to be presented differently based on what cell is selected.

In the detail view you can see that there is no data for 'From' and 'Receiver'

How would I go about hiding those UILabels and their counterparts (meaning the UILabel where the data is populated beside).

Is this even possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: could you add some code to show your work. Have you considered using a stack-view for your labels .

Comment: What Code would be useful for you to see? I have not been able to write and code for this problem. And yes those UILabels are all in stackViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad()` (or wherever you setup the detail view), simply hiding empty labels will mean the `UIStackView` will slide the remaining labels into position. You will need an `IBOutlet` to the labels of course (or have generated them in code).

Here is an example with a variable `receiver` which is either nil or has data that would go into the "Receiver" field:

```
if receiver != nil {
    receiverNameLabel.isHidden = false
    receiverDataLabel.isHidden = false
    receiverLabel.text = "Text from your data here"
} else {
    receiverNameLabel.isHidden = true
    receiverDataLabel.isHidden = true
    receiverLabel.text = ""
```

The `UISTackView` will do the rest. If the left and right sections are in two separate stack views, make sure they have the same settings (fill etc) so that when a "row" of labels disappears, the others remain aligned.

Comment: Awesome answer! I was obviously overthinking this. I had to change the != to be == "" as my data was populating empty strings as nil data.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri Thanks - I have used this sort of approach in my own app. Stack views are great!